# installing application packages on ubuntu usb

Tags: startup-applications

I'm new to ubuntu. I downloaded the newest version on a usb stick then I booted my PC with the usb. upon trying out ubuntu I tried installing additional packages/applications, which worked fine. 
BUT when I then after tried using my ubuntu usb, the new installed apps were not there!
if I get that right, ubuntu would only install new packages to the actual PC I'm using it on. not within ubuntu itself!?
is there a way that I can install new applications to my ubuntu usb and it should stay within ubuntu so I can use it for other pc's which don't have an internet connection necessary to update/install packages ?
thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're encountering is that by default the USB is loading the Ubuntu Install ISO as a CD which is Read-Only. This means that, yes, "Try Ubuntu" will load Ubuntu into RAM and everything done inside Ubuntu is deleted upon Shutdown of the PC. However, you can create a Bootable USB that does save your Files and Settings.

Simply follow the steps in the Below Guide and make sure to choose the "Stored in reserved extra space" option:

[Create a Bootable USB Stick Using Ubuntu - Ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)